# Another In Place Editor - a jQuery edit in place plugin

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

I'm trying to figure out how to get the changed value to submit to the database but so far ive not had much luck at all. any idea as to what i am doing wrong?

JS FILE:

```
$("#editme5").editInPlace({
    /*saving_animation_color: "#ECF2F8",
    callback: function(idOfEditor, enteredText, orinalHTMLContent, settingsParams, animationCallbacks) {
        animationCallbacks.didStartSaving();
        setTimeout(animationCallbacks.didEndSaving, 2000);
        return enteredText;
    },*/
    url: "server.php",
    params: "name=BUSINESS_NAME"
});
```

PHP FILE:

```
include('database.php');
$_GET['name'];
$_NAME=$_GET['name'];

$update = $_POST['update_value'];
$insert = "UPDATE CLIENTS SET ".$_NAME."='".$update."'";
mysql_query($insert) or die (mysql_error());
```

Comment: And we should just KNOW what editor you're using and how it submits the form? Nice SQL injection holes, by the way. Hope you'll enjoy havinug your database trashed.

Comment: I already know that. I just want to get stuff working first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing:

```
include('database.php');
$_GET['name'];
$_NAME=$_GET['name'];
```

To:

```
include('database.php');
$_NAME=$_POST['name'];
```

The documentation says:

> Once the in-place editor form is submitted, it sends a POST request to
>   the URL that is specified in the editor’s parameters along with three
>   form fields

By writing `$_NAME=$_GET['name'];` you were expecting the value come over a `GET` request, but the plugin sends the value using a `POST` request. That's what is the culprit here, I suppose.

Also, keep in mind what Marc B said in his comment. The code is very vunerable to SQL injection attacks. To make it less vunerable, use **at least** `mysql_real_escape_string()` (more: http://php.net/manual/pl/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) or use prepared statements (a good tutorial: http://www.ultramegatech.com/2009/07/using-mysql-prepared-statements-in-php/).

Comment: Techically, this editor of the OP's could be using both query strings AND post data, but we just can't tell. However, passing DB field names around from client-side is even more hideous than plain SQL injection holes.

Answer (score 1):

try using `$_REQUEST` which can help you capture both `$_GET` and `$_POST` request at the sample time ...

Try fixing SQL Injection holes with `mysql_real_escape_string` see http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php for more information

Thanks